# How do I select elements whose class name starts with a specific word?

Tags: javascript, dom

My goal, for example, is to select elements that have a class starting with the word "child-1".

```
var childs = document.querySelectorAll("#child-" + i);
```

This code can only select the class name "child-x".

```
<li class="child-1-5">
<li class="child-1-8">
<li class="child-1-9">
```

How do I select elements that begin with Child1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
var childs = document.querySelectorAll("li[class^='child-1']");
```

If you'd like to select the first number dynamically with your parameter, just escape to the variable:

```js
var i = 1;
var childs = document.querySelectorAll("li[class^='child-" + i + "']");
```

```html
<li class="child-1-5">5
<li class="child-1-8">8
<li class="child-1-9">9
```

Comment: How do I add a variable "i" instead of "1"?

Comment: @EminYILMAZ I thought you wanted all elements whose class begins with child-1? That's what the last sentence in your question states. Perhaps I misunderstood?

Comment: I wrote it as an example. I should call "child -" + x according to the parameter that comes to my function.

Comment: @EminYILMAZ I edited let me know if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: @EminYILMAZ Whoops I left in a single quote on the escape. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS [wildcards](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wildcard-selectors-and-in-css-for-classes/) for that:

```js
const children = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="child-"], [class*=" child-"]');
console.log(children);
```

```html
<li class="child-1-5">
<li class="child-1-8">
<li class="child-1-9">
<li class="some classes child-1-10 to make noise">
```

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)